# db2 ibm_db.execute_many kept on crashing

Tags: python, db2

I am trying to insert a pandas dataframe with a shape of (3695, 32) to a db2 table.

I already converted the dataframe into a tuple of tuples and used the code below:

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO MYSCHEMA.TABLE1 VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"

stmt = ibm_db.prepare(connection, sql)
ibm_db.execute_many(stmt, my_tuple)
```

However, every time I run the code the kernel stops without any error messages. Is this possibly caused by the size of my dataframe?

EDIT:
I use python 3.7.5rci, ibm_db 2.0.9, db2 jdbc driver, DB2 on IBM Cloud running on windows 10 and the table consists of the following data types: varchar, char, decimal, date, integer, timestamp

Comment: Please edit your question to add facts about your environment versions (o/s, python version, ibm_db version, which Db2-driver you are using, which Db2-server platform).  Also, detail the column-datatypes of the 32-columns (are they all the same column datatype?).  You can find what is really happening by taking a trace with the `db2trc` tool (look in the Db2 Knowledge Center online for all the details of how to do this).

Comment: Also, is there some reason for not using the pandas dataframe `to_sql()` method?

Comment: Consider using the currently shipping version of ibm_db (3.0.2 at current date).  It should not crash, but it may throw an error instead.  If it still crashes, then you should use `db2trc` as mentioned previously. Also, examine the pandas `to_sql()` method.

Comment: Hi, @mao thank you so much for this. I resorted to using the `to_sql()` method instead.